# Sparse matrix multiplication using MKL

Tags: c, openmp, intel, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I am implementing sparse matrix multiplication using `MKL` library and benchmarking on various Intel processors like Intel Xeon E5 and Intel Xeon Phi.
Although I am able to benchmark with satisfactory results on Xeon E5, everytime I run the same code on Xeon Phi, I get segmentation fault after 3 iterations from the called `"mkl_dcsrmultcsr"` function. I am not able to figure out the reason for this, please let me know what might be the reason.
Following is the code

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "time.h"
    #include "omp.h"
    #include "mkl.h"
    #include "mkl_spblas.h"

    double timerval ()
    {
        struct timeval st;
        gettimeofday(&st, NULL);
        return (st.tv_sec+st.tv_usec*1e-6);
    }

    int main(){

    double *nz, *nzc;
    int *ia,*ja, *ic,*jc,*pos;
    int info=1;

    int i, j, k;
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3,*fp4;

    double avg_time = 0, s_time, e_time;
    //open file to write results
    //FILE *fp1;

    char trans = 'N';   
    int sort = 1;

    int m=4;
    int iterations;
    int request = 0;

    /* iterate the loop for input size from 2exp3 to 2exp10 */
    for (iterations=0; iterations<8; iterations++)
    {
        m *= 2; // increase the dimension of Matrix with every iteration
        int n = m; // Assuming a square matrix.
        int nzmax =m*n ;
        double dense_const = 0.05;
        int temp5, temp6,temp3,temp4;
        int density=(m*n)*(dense_const);

        //memory allocation for matrix A and B
        nz = calloc((m*n),sizeof(double));
        ia = calloc((m*n),sizeof(int));
        ja = calloc((m*n),sizeof(int));

        //memory allocation for product matrix C
        nzc =calloc((m*n),sizeof(double));
        ic = calloc((m*n),sizeof(int));
        jc = calloc((m*n),sizeof(int));
        //Configuration parameters
        k=0;
        //density of the sparse matrix to be created. Assume 5% density.
        //position array for random initialisation of positions in input matrix
        pos= calloc((m*n), sizeof(int));
        int temp,temp1;

        //  printf("the density is %d\n",density);
        //  printf("check 1:\n");

        //randomly initialise positions
        for(i=0;i<density;i++)
        {
            temp1=rand()%(m*n);
            pos[i]=temp1;   
        }
        //  printf("check 2:\n");

        //sort the 'pos' array
        for (i = 0 ; i < density; i++) 
        {
            int d = i;
            int t;

            while ( d > 0 && pos[d] < pos[d-1]) 
            {
                t = pos[d];
                pos[d]   = pos[d-1];
                pos[d-1] = t;
                d--;
            }
        }
        //printf("check 3:\n");

        // initialise with non zero elements and extract column and row ptr vector
        j=1;
        ja[0]=1;

        int p=0;
        for(i = 0; i < density; i++)
        {
            temp=pos[i];
            nz[k] = rand();
            // nz[k] = 1;

            ia[k] = temp%m;
            k++;
            p++;
            temp5= pos[i];
            temp6=pos[i+1];

            temp3=temp5-(temp5%m);
            temp4=temp6-(temp6%m);

            if(!(temp3== temp4))
            {   
                if((temp3+m==temp6))
                            {}

                else    
                {   
                    ja[j]=p+1;
                    j++;
                }
            }       
        }
        printf("check1\n");

        request = 0;
        s_time = timerval();
        for(i=0; i<1000;i++)
        {       
            #pragma omp parallel
            {
             mkl_dcsrmultcsr(&trans, &request, &sort, &n, &n, &n, nz, ia, ja, nz, ia, ja, nzc, jc, ic, &nzmax, &info);
            }
        }
        e_time = timerval();
        avg_time = (e_time - s_time);

        /* write the timing information in "output.txt"*/
        avg_time = avg_time / 1000;

        printf("check 5:\n");
        if((fp2 = fopen("output.txt","a"))==NULL)
        {
            printf("error opening file\n");
        }
        //fseek(fp1,1000,SEEK_END);
        fprintf (fp2, "\n Input size: %d x %d ,Time: %lf and density is %d and info is %d \n", m,n, avg_time, density,info); 
        fclose(fp2);

        //mkl_free_buffers();

        free(ja);
        free(ia);
        free(nz);

        free(pos);  
        free(jc);
        free(ic);
        free(nzc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a comment on your Xeon Phi problem. But I'm curious why you're benchmarking with a random matrix? I'm new to sparse matrices but it seems to me the topology of the sparse matrix can have a enormous effect on the performance of the operation (at least for Cholesky decomposition). From what it seems so far random matrices give the least improvement from analyzing the topology (i.e. finding a permutation matrix).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Zboson, I am aware of performance variations by using a random matrix. But, I really am not sure how to generate a matrix of CSR format for different matrix sizes. Can you please let me know of any functions/libraries which can generate CSR format matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mkl_(thread_)free_buffers() before a call to the multiplication functions. That worked out for me!